# Is Stanford NLP SUTime timezone aware?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sutime

We currently use SUTime to help find and normalize date times.   However, we've noticed some oddities with relative dates like "today" or "yesterday" especially when crossing over UTC day boundaries (i.e if it is the next day in UTC time and "yesterday is passed in you'll get the current date)

We tried passing in an ISO formatted string with timezone offsets to compensate but this didn't appear to have the desired behavior.   In fact, it started causing other issues where times like "Today" were now on the next day.

Is SUTime timezone aware?  Can we pass in an ISO string like this '2020-11-23T20:47:45-08:00'?  If not is there some other format that would work .. or is it not possible?